# Find the documents which contains a specific value in a array

Tags: mongodb

I want to find documents that contain a single - (symbol).

occupationalCategory array consists of single - (symbol) instead of a double on specific employerId.

wrongly inserted with (single - symbol)
"occupationalCategory" : [
"15-1132.00 - Software Developers, Applications"
],

its should be : (double -- symbol)
"occupationalCategory" : [
"15-1132.00 -- Software Developers, Applications"
]

Please help me to get those documents.

Comment: Is it just a single value "15-1132.00 - Software Developers, Applications" (that you insert wrongly) or the attached value is a kind of pattern? If it is a pattern, does this pattern is consistent to the documents? And try to explain more the pattern.

Comment: The attached value is a kind of pattern and the pattern is consistent.
it's like 'code-some value'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mentioned that the string pattern is consistent, you can use regex to match the string pattern.

```
^\d+-\d+.\d{2} - [\w\s]+, \w+$
```

`^` - Start with

`\d` - Match with digit

`+` - Refer previous character/symbol with at least 1 occurrence

`-` -  `-` Symbol

`\d+.\d{2}` - Match for decimal pattern

`\w` - Word character

`\s` - Spacing character

`$` - Match End

[Sample Regex 101 & Test Output](https://regex101.com/r/pBKQKk/1)

```
db.collection.find({
  "occupationalCategory": {
    $regex: "\\d+-\\d+.\\d{2} - [\\w\\s]+, \\w+",
    $options: "m"
  }
})
```

[Sample Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/twCxkMXLqpM)

Comment: Thank you so much @Yong Shun !!
sorry for the confusion, the documents might be in this pattern as well.
"151132.00 - Software Developers" or "1511-32.00 - Software"
And also I need to update the same collection as the below example(coma separated instead of -).
"15-1132.00" , "Software Developers, Applications"

Comment: Maybe something like [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Az3M3GQGi3u)? FYI, would suggest to create another question with provide concrete explanation and sample for better tracing, thanks.